# Numerically definite quantification in logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am attempting to translate the following sentence into formal logic:

"At most, two people are strong and they hate each other" 
Where Sx: x is strong and Hxy: x hates y

I have translated this as:

(∃x)(∃y)(Sx^Sy)^Sz)->(x=y∨x=z)^(Hxy^Hyx)

However I am not sure whether the order should look more like this:

(∃x)(∃y)(x=y∨x=z)->(Sx^Sy)^Sz)^(Hxy^Hyx)

I would appreciate any help in clarifying this, thank you.

I am a beginner in logic, so please do not judge my attempts too harshly!

Comment: "at most" needs $(∃x)(∃y)(Sx \land Sy \land \forall z \ (Sz \to (x=z \lor x=z)) \ldots)$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where you said '"at most" needs '...(x=z∨x=z))...)', did you mean to say '...(x=y∨x=z))...)'? Or is 'x=y' unnecessary?

Comment: I think its $...\forall{z}{(Sz \rightarrow (x=z \vee y=z))}...$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very awkward English statement, and it is quite ambiguous to me.

I can see at least three different readings:

1. *There are definitely two people that are strong and they hate each other, but that there are no other strong people*

This would translate as:

$$\exists x \exists y (x \not = y \land Sx \land Sy \land \forall z (Sz \rightarrow (z= x \lor z = y) \land Hxy \land Hyx)$$

2. *There are at most two strong people, and whenever you have two strong people they will hate each other*

This would translate as:

$$\forall x \forall y ((x \not = y \land Sx \land Sy) \rightarrow (\forall z (Sz \rightarrow (z= x \lor z = y))  \land Hxy)) $$

3. *There is at most 1 pair of strong people hating each other (so you may have other strong people, but there would be no more than one mutual hate relationship between two strong people)*

This would translate as:

$$\forall x \forall y ((x \not = y \land Sx \land Sy \land Hxy \land Hyx) \rightarrow \forall v \forall w ((v \not = w \land Sv \land Sw \land Hvw \land Hwv) \rightarrow ((v = x \land w = y) \lor (v = y \land w = x))))$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your in depth response. I agree that the sentence is very ambiguous and could be taken to mean many different things. I'm inclined to take the second sentence ('There are at most two strong people, and whenever you have two strong people they will hate each other') to be correct, as this is what I interpreted the sentence to mean prima facie.

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help 

Comment: Hi sorry just to follow up on this, could you also translate the second example this without the x≠y. I.e: ∀x∀y((Sx∧Sy)→(∀z(Sz→(z=x∨z=y))∧Hxy)). I ask because I haven't seen 'at most two' being formulated with 'x≠y', but just like this '∀x∀y∀z (x = y ∨ y = z ∨ x = z)'.

Comment: @coops33 I added the $x \not = y$ as I figured the 'not hating each other ' part is about two different people . So this way you can still have several strong people hating themselves, which I didn't think the statement had anything to say about.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for clarifying that!